# Função jQuery não funciona dentro de if

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
function formataPorcentuaisMensais(){
    var cancelamento = $("#cancelamentoMes").text().replace('%','');
    var aproveitamento = $("#aproveitamentoMes").text().replace('%','');
    var primCompras = $("#primComprasMes").text().replace('%','');
    var juros = $("#jurosMes").text().replace('%','');
    var seguros = $("#segurosMes").text().replace('%','');

    if(cancelamento >= 4 && cancelamento <= 6){
        cancelamento.css({'background-color': 'yellow', 'color': 'black'});
    }
}

$(function(){
formataPorcentuaisMensais();
});
```

Aparentemente está correto mas diz que a função `cancelamento.css` não é uma função, alguém sabe oq pode ser?

*Estou com o jquery carregado;
**Todas as variáveis estão funcionando.

Obrigado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ao executar essa linha:

```
var cancelamento = $("#cancelamentoMes").text().replace('%','');
```

A variável cancelamento recebe o elemento #cancelamentoMes, pega o texto dele e troca todos os % por nada, através da função replace. Logo, cancelamento é uma string, você pode ter certeza disso se usar um `console.log(cancelamento);`.

Ao usar `cancelamento.css()` você está chamando a função css, porém essa função não é uma função de string. O correto seria: `$("#cancelamentoMes").css();`

Seu if ficaria assim:

```
if(cancelamento >= 4 && cancelamento <= 6){
    $("#cancelamentoMes").css({'background-color': 'yellow', 'color': 'black'});
}
```

Comment: muito obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente. Só não entendi como a função .css não trata com string mas funcionou apenas chamando o elemente com id #cancelamentoMes

Comment: A função css não pertence às strings, você não pode alterar o css de uma string, pois uma string não tem CSS, é apenas texto. Você pode alterar o CSS de um elemento HTML, como uma div. Nesse caso, o elemento #cancelamentoMes. Para pegar esse elemento você usa $("#cancelamentoMes"). Entende?

Comment: Perfeitamente @André, grato!